Loss is zero while training ViTPose (Vision Transformer) with custom dataset
I am trying to fine tuning ViTPose Base trained on COCO 256x192. At the beginning of the training my losses are already zero.
2024-06-05 17:09:38,939 - mmpose - INFO - Epoch [1][1/18]       lr: 2.376e-10, eta: 14 days, 5:07:40, time: 682.635, data_time: 2.816, heatmap_loss: 0.0000, acc_pose: 0.0000, loss: 0.0000, grad_norm: 0.0000
Debugging I've seen that the target tensor is composed of all zeros.
target. Any() = False and the losses object is {'heatmap_loss': tensor(0., grad_fn=<MulBackward0>), 'acc_pose': 0.0}.
Does anyone know why is that?
My train.json and val.json follow this format (as seen in the documentation):
[ {     "image_file": "100-0.png",
        "image_size": [ ... ],
        "bbox": [ ... ],
        "keypoints": [ ... ] ,
 ... } ]

The images are all in images folder.
The train.py class is as follows:
from config_test import get_config
from mmpose.datasets import build_dataset
from mmpose.models import build_posenet
from mmpose.apis import train_model
import mmcv

# config
cfg = get_config()

# build dataset
datasets = [build_dataset(cfg.data.train)]

# build model
model = build_posenet(cfg.model)

# create work_dir
mmcv.mkdir_or_exist(cfg.work_dir)

# train model
train_model(model, datasets, cfg, distributed=False, validate=True, meta=dict())

The config are taken from get_config() method in the config class.
from mmengine.config import Config
def get_config():
    cfg = Config.fromfile('ViTPose/configs/body/2d_kpt_sview_rgb_img/topdown_heatmap/coco/ViTPose_base_coco_256x192.py')

    # set basic configs
    cfg.data_root = 'path'
    cfg.work_dir = 'path'
    cfg.gpu_ids = range(1)
    cfg.seed = 0

    # set log interval
    cfg.log_config.interval = 1

    # set evaluation configs
    cfg.evaluation.interval = 10
    cfg.evaluation.metric = 'PCK'
    cfg.evaluation.save_best = 'PCK'

    # set batch size
    cfg.data.samples_per_gpu = 16
    cfg.data.val_dataloader = dict(samples_per_gpu=16)
    cfg.data.test_dataloader = dict(samples_per_gpu=16)

    # set dataset configs
    cfg.data.train.type = 'Custom Dataset Name'
    cfg.data.train.ann_file = 'path'
    cfg.data.train.img_prefix = 'path'

    cfg.data.val.type = 'Custom Dataset Name'
    cfg.data.val.ann_file = 'path'
    cfg.data.val.img_prefix = 'path'

    cfg.data.test.type = 'Custom Dataset Name'
    cfg.data.test.ann_file = 'path'
    cfg.data.test.img_prefix = 'path'
    return cfg

Most of the config though are taken from ViTPose_base_coco_256x192.py class.
_base_ = [
    '../../../../_base_/default_runtime.py',
    '../../../../_base_/datasets/my_custom_dataset.py'
]
evaluation = dict(interval=10, metric='mAP', save_best='AP')

optimizer = dict(type='AdamW', lr=1e-5, betas=(0.9, 0.999), weight_decay=0.1,
                 constructor='LayerDecayOptimizerConstructor', 
                 paramwise_cfg=dict(
                                    num_layers=12, 
                                    layer_decay_rate=0.75,
                                    custom_keys={
                                            'bias': dict(decay_multi=0.),
                                            'pos_embed': dict(decay_mult=0.),
                                            'relative_position_bias_table': dict(decay_mult=0.),
                                            'norm': dict(decay_mult=0.)
                                            }
                                    )
                )

optimizer_config = dict(grad_clip=dict(max_norm=1., norm_type=2))

# learning policy
lr_config = dict(
    policy='step',
    warmup='linear',
    warmup_iters=10,
    warmup_ratio=0.001,
    step=[17, 35])
total_epochs = 100
target_type = 'GaussianHeatmap'
channel_cfg = dict(
    num_output_channels=12, # this value has been changed since I only have 12 keypoints in my custom dataset
    dataset_joints=12, # this value has been changed since I only have 12 keypoints in my custom dataset
    dataset_channel=[
       list(range(12)) # this value has been changed since I only have 12 keypoints in my custom dataset
    ],
    inference_channel=list(range(12))) # this value has been changed since I only have 12 keypoints in my custom dataset

# model settings
model = dict(
    type='TopDown',
    pretrained='path',
    backbone=dict(
        type='ViT',
        img_size=(256, 192),
        patch_size=16,
        embed_dim=768,
        depth=12,
        num_heads=12,
        ratio=1,
        use_checkpoint=True,
        mlp_ratio=4,
        qkv_bias=True,
        drop_path_rate=0.3,
    ),
    keypoint_head=dict(
        type='TopdownHeatmapSimpleHead',
        in_channels=768,
        num_deconv_layers=2,
        num_deconv_filters=(256, 256),
        num_deconv_kernels=(4, 4),
        extra=dict(final_conv_kernel=1, ),
        out_channels=channel_cfg['num_output_channels'],
        loss_keypoint=dict(type='JointsMSELoss', use_target_weight=True)),
    train_cfg=dict(),
    test_cfg=dict(
        flip_test=False,
        post_process='default',
        shift_heatmap=False,
        target_type=target_type,
        modulate_kernel=11,
        use_udp=True))

data_cfg = dict(
    image_size=[192, 256],
    heatmap_size=[48, 64],
    num_output_channels=channel_cfg['num_output_channels'],
    num_joints=channel_cfg['dataset_joints'],
    dataset_channel=channel_cfg['dataset_channel'],
    inference_channel=channel_cfg['inference_channel'],
    soft_nms=False,
    nms_thr=1.0,
    oks_thr=0.9,
    vis_thr=0.2,
    use_gt_bbox=False,
    det_bbox_thr=0.0,
    bbox_file='path',
)

train_pipeline = [
    dict(type='LoadImageFromFile'),
    dict(
        type='TopDownHalfBodyTransform',
        num_joints_half_body=8,
        prob_half_body=0.3),
    dict(
        type='TopDownGetRandomScaleRotation', rot_factor=40, scale_factor=0.5),
    dict(type='TopDownAffine', use_udp=True),
    dict(type='ToTensor'),
    dict(
        type='NormalizeTensor',
        mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
        std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]),
    dict(
        type='TopDownGenerateTarget',
        sigma=2,
        encoding='UDP',
        target_type=target_type),
    dict(
        type='Collect',
        keys=['img', 'target', 'target_weight'],
        meta_keys=[
            'image_file', 'joints_3d', 'joints_3d_visible', 'center', 'scale',
            'rotation', 'bbox_score'
        ]),
]

val_pipeline = [
    dict(type='LoadImageFromFile'),
    dict(type='TopDownAffine', use_udp=True),
    dict(type='ToTensor'),
    dict(type='NormalizeTensor',
        mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
        std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]),
    dict(type='Collect', keys=['img'], meta_keys=['image_file', 'center', 'scale', 'rotation', 'bbox_score']),
]

test_pipeline = val_pipeline

data_root = 'path'
data = dict(
    samples_per_gpu=64,
    workers_per_gpu=4,
    val_dataloader=dict(samples_per_gpu=32),
    test_dataloader=dict(samples_per_gpu=32),
    train=dict(
        type='Custom Dataset Name',
        ann_file='path',
        img_prefix='path',
        data_cfg=data_cfg,
        pipeline=train_pipeline,
        dataset_info={{_base_.dataset_info}}),
    val=dict(
        type='Custom Dataset Name',
        ann_file='path',
        img_prefix='path',
        data_cfg=data_cfg,
        pipeline=val_pipeline,
        dataset_info={{_base_.dataset_info}}),
    test=dict(
        type='Custom Dataset Name',
        ann_file='path',
        img_prefix='path',
        data_cfg=data_cfg,
        pipeline=test_pipeline,
        dataset_info={{_base_.dataset_info}}),
)

